# How do you pass a VB string argument to a function written in C?

Tags: visual-c++, vb6

I have a problem here: I'm trying to pass a VB6 string to a function written in C, but I think it is different from LPSTR. When the function is called, my VB6 IDE crashes. How do I pass a VB string as an argument to a function in C? Below is my code. Thanks to all:

VB6

```
Private Declare Function WritestStr Lib “teststr.dll” (ByRef mystr As String) As Long

Private Sub command1_Click()

    Dim mystr as string

    Call WritestStr(mystr)
    Msgbox mystr

End Sub
```

VC6

```
include “windows.h”

Int __stdcall WritestStr(LPSTR *mystr)
{
    *mystr = “Venancio Guedes”;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's been eons since I wrote VB/Win32 function declarations, but I'm fairly sure I remember that by default all parameters to an external library function in VB6 are passed byref; however, the VB6 String type is already a pointer-based type, so a byref parameter that is already passed byref pushes the wrong value onto the stack. That causes the reference to crash inside the DLL. Try passing it ByVal, instead, because the "value" of the parameter is really the string pointer itself, which is what the DLL function expects.

As I said, its been a looong time since I wrote these kinds of declarations, so all standard caveats apply, but I'm pretty sure that's close.

Good luck!

**EDIT** The ByVal declaration for the DLL function is correct. The fix now should be for you to initialize/allocate the string before the call to the DLL function with spaces, eg:

```
Dim vbString as String
Dim result as Long
vbString = Space$(255) ' just make sure this number is large enough
result = WritestStr(vbString)
```

Comment: I tried to pass ByVal statement in vb as you said however still fighting, shows no errors just lock and close the IDE, I used an int instead of String and it works perfectly I'm just getting use String

Comment: Before you call the function (with the String passed ByVal), initialize it with something like that I added to the solution above...

Comment: If this fixes your problem, I might ask you to "accept" the answer if you would...

Comment: DavidW is correct, use ByVal, and pre-initialize the string buffer in VB6 before calling the dll function.

Comment: Thank you all I got such a following in the microsoft site http://support.microsoft.com/kb/187912/pt-br

Comment: @Venâncio Guedes - did you actually test David's code? It sounds as if you didn't.

Answer (score 2):

VB strings are called BSTR in the OLE documentation, and is almost compatible with LPWSTR. They are null terminated 2 byte per character Unicode (UTF-16) strings, but with a 32 bit length immediately before the memory the string pointer points to.

Your code uses LPSTR*, which is a pointer to a pointer to a 1 byte per character ANSI string. Obviously, you are doing this so as to return your string to the VB6 code.

Unfortunately, these two are incompatible.

The reason why the code crashes is that you are passing the VB6 variable <mystr> to your function, but by default it is set to vbNullString, which is like:

```
BSTR mystr = NULL;
```

But your main problem is that VB cannot possibly use your C function as written. There is no way of writing a Declare statement for LPSTR*. If you changed your C code to

```
include “windows.h”

Int __stdcall WritestStr(LPSTR mystr)
{
    const LPSTR myconststr = “Venancio Guedes”;

    if (mystr)
        int destlen = strlen(mystr);
        int srclen = strlen(myconststr);
        if (destlen >= srclen)
        {
            strcpy(mystr, myconststr);
            return 0;
        }
    return srclen;
}
```

... you could change the declare to:

```
Private Declare Function WritestStr Lib “teststr.dll” (ByVal mystr As String) As Long
```

... and ensure you declare a buffer to accept the string.
 You *could* write a Declare statement for LPSTR, but you need to

```
Private Sub command1_Click()

    Dim mystr As string
    Dim nLen As Long

    mystr = Space$(1024)
    nLen = WritestStr(mystr)

    Msgbox Left$(mystr, nLen)

End Sub
```

This is very reminiscent of how most Win32 API functions work.

Passing mystr as ByVal informs VB6 that it must copy <mystr> from BSTR to a temporary LPSTR, and pass a pointer to that buffer. When it has finished executing WriteStr() it then copies the LPSTR buffer back to the original BSTR.

Allocating a VB string buffer <mystr> to pass to your function gives you something to write back into.

Alternatively, you could rewrite your C program to accept a BSTR natively (the cleanest and more portable solution if you want to have mult-languages). In which case your original VB6 declaration would stand i.e. ByRef mystr As String. Unfortunately, you would still have to write into a buffer like you are doing here.

If you want to have LPWSTR*, LPSTR* or BSTR* you will have to declare your function in a type library - something I don't have the time here to talk about.

Comment: Thank you all I got such a following in the microsoft site http://support.microsoft.com/kb/187912/pt-br

Comment: Well, there's one thank you that we would definitely appreciate!

Comment: For a start, did this work? I actually took the time to create a C++ DLL to test out what I said above. With due respect to David W, I can't see how his solution could have worked with the code you gave us. LPSTR * would have not worked as a way to pass back a string to VB.